# C++ - Declaring reference variables inside loops?

Tags: c++, variables, loops, reference, declaration

As I know, declaration of variables of POD types or primitive types inside loops is OK (no overhead).

How about reference variables?
Does it matter to performance, to declare reference variables inside loops?

For example, a variable references to a vector, like below:

```
vector<vector<int> > data (100, vector<int> (100));
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    vector<int> &row = data[i];
    ...
}
```

There will be no overhead, right?

Thank you.

Comment: You could also use "for (auto& row : data) {} " if using c++11

Comment: Did you try timing the difference with alternative codes? What would an alternative be? Why do you want to declare inside the loop?

Comment: `<!-- insert note about premature optimization below -->`

Comment: @Floris Sorry I didn't try yet, and the purpose is to make the code clean, when the code inside a loop just uses a specific row. And to H2CO3, this situation.

Comment: @H2CO3: It's not that premature.  This isn't a microoptimization, it's over a 40kb structure.  If this is inside a loop, it would make a very significant difference.

Comment: @Wug: and of course you profiled?

Comment: @Fanael: of course I didn't.  But working entirely with temporary copies would require 80kb of extra copying.  Depending on exactly what kind of manipulations you're doing on this data, you'd find practical speedups of anywhere between 3x faster (if every value is updated once) and 50x faster (if only a few are updated).

Comment: Gotta say, this looks like a simple matter of reference cleanliness to me (`row` rather than `data[i]` can be helpful), and I don't see that there's anything wrong with spending time checking your understanding of the effects your choices have when you're learning.  So as Wug says it's purely a question of aesthetics here; personally, I like the results of your condensing the reference into a single name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a performance standpoint, references are as computationally complex as pointers (and typically are implemented internally in the same way).

Initializing the reference itself has no more overhead then initializing a pointer.

Though, based on your use case, you would probably find it easier and equally efficient (if slightly more verbose) to use an iterator.

```
vector<vector<int> > data (100, vector<int> (100));
for (vector<vector<int> >::iterator row = data.begin(); row != data.end(); ++row) {
    // (*row)[0] = 1;
}
```

Comment: for the record, iterators are usually designed with efficient traversal in mind and are often better than doing something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no overhead because a reference is basically a memory location.
In a 32-bit application, a memory location is 4 bytes, so declaring that thing inside the loop has the same overhead as declaring an `int`: negligible.

Comment: Any time brethren. (I didn't say 'bro' because of the char count range)